# Persist LocalDateTime as ISO-String in sqlite-db using hibernate

Tags: java, sqlite, hibernate

I have a Sqlite-DB with the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id bigint not null, from datetime, to datetime, (...) primary key (id));
```

Corresponding hibernate-entity is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "from")
    private LocalDateTime from;
    @Column(name = "to")
    private LocalDateTime to;
    ...

}
```

When persisting such an entity, hibernate always inserts the LocalDateTime-fields as int (unix timestamp).

Is there any way to have hibernate inserting these timestamps as ISO-Strings? According to [sqlite-documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html), sqlite is capable of storing dates in one the following formats, so it is at least technically possible to do so:

> SQLite does not have a storage class set aside for storing dates
> and/or times. Instead, the built-in Date And Time Functions of SQLite
> are capable of storing dates and times as TEXT, REAL, or INTEGER
> values:
>
> TEXT as ISO8601 strings ("YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS").
>
> REAL as Julian day numbers, the number of days since noon in Greenwich
> on November 24, 4714 B.C. according to the proleptic Gregorian
> calendar.
>
> INTEGER as Unix Time, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00
> UTC.

I already did try to override SqliteDialect, but it did not change anything:

```
public class MySqliteDialect extends SQLiteDialect {

    public MySqliteDialect() {
        super();
        registerColumnType( Types.TIMESTAMP, "text" );
    }
}
```

**tl;dr: How can I store LocalDateTime fields from entity in datetime-column in sqlite-db as ISO-string?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why this is only barely documented, but it turned out there is an property in the sqlite-jbdc driver, that controls this behaviour:
[image]

Therefore the solution for my problem was setting **data_class** property to **TEXT** in hibernate-properties:

```
properties.setProperty("hibernate.connection.date_class", "TEXT");
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023, using Hibernate 5 with SpringBoot 2.7.9 and the SQLite JDBC driver 3.42.0.0, I couldn't set this through Hibernate. Instead, I used the pragma directives in the connection string: `jdbc:sqlite:file:mydb.db?date_class=TEXT`.

Either Hikari doesn't use them, or Hibernate doesn't pass them. The pragma parameter works fine. The value is case insensitive as SQLite converts it to uppercase. [Reference](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/14e5eb81f21aa1554b3e68c543ee528213b8140c/src/main/java/org/sqlite/SQLiteConnectionConfig.java#L25)